Connect Dialogflow CX to a digital human using Trulience
I am working on a school assignment and I need to connect the agent I created in Dialogflow CX with an avatar or digital human from Trulience however I have been finding it very difficult to connect them.
Do I need to use the OAuth to connect them to connect the created conversation in Dialogflow CX to the avatar or digital human from Trulience?
In the setting, it asks for a Digital Human Config URL and that you need to create and/or host your own bespoke Digital Human configuration file.  It mentions you can use the SSML, however where do I need to get this Config Url from ?
I don't really understand how to connect them so any help would be really appreciated to connect the dialogflow to trulience for my school assignment.
